# Clamping pitch in first person camera using quaternion orientation

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, eigen

I'm building a simple first person camera that assumes the up vector always matches the world +Z axis, i.e. no roll.

I'm using a quaternion to store the orientation of the camera. (I'm trying to stay away from Euler angles.)

Now, say I want to restrict the possible pitch of the camera to something like -85 to 85 degrees of pitch. That means that when I apply some additional pitch to the camera, I'll need to have some sort of logic that restricts the pitch if it exceeds the aforementioned threshold.

**What's an efficient way to do this given that the camera's orientation is stored as a quaternion?**

My current thought is to extract the forward(i.e. look At) and right vectors from the quaternion. Project the forward vector and the global X or Y vector into a plane formed by the right vector's normal and then find the angular difference between these projected vectors. That seems like a lot of math to do though every time I change the pitch. Assuming that is even a valid solution, I'm wondering if there is a better and simpler way...

Here is my current pitch setting code (using Eigen math library):

```
void Camera::pitch(float angleInRadians)
{
    if (angleInRadians != 0.0)
    {

        // TODO: Apply pitch restriction. <----------------- how?

        mRotation *= Quaternionf(AngleAxisf(-angleInRadians, Vector3f::UnitX()));
        mRotation.normalize();

        mIsViewMatrixDirty = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving this by tracking pitch as a member variable. The actual orientation is still stored in a quaternion.

Anytime I accumulated pitch into the orientation via the `pitch()` function or reset the pitch by using the `lookAt(vec3 target)` function (which was not posted in the original question), this pitch member variable is updated accordingly.

In the `lookAt` function, I calculated pitch by using `asin(direction.y())`. If the pitch exceeded the bounds, an assertion is thrown (rather than correcting it).

In the `pitch(float angleDelta)` function, the pitch delta is corrected if it exceeds the min/max bounds. After applying the appropriate restriction to the delta, it is accumulated into the quaternion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you have to worry about the quaternion in this situation; you situation is concerned about the angle in radians that represents your rotation either it be pitch, yaw or roll. You want to prevent this angle from going beyond bounds or to have a specific range. To do this is quite simple; all you need is a constrain or clamp function.

```
template<class T>
inline void clamp( T min, T max, T &value ) {    
    if ( value < min ) {
        value = min;
        return;
    }

    if ( value > max ) {
        value = max;
    }    
} // clamp
```

Once you have this handy generic math function available to use, you then have two options: either you can set the bounds within this function call so that it is predetermined or you can modify your existing pitch function's signature to include two more values so that the caller or user can set these appropriately. Then within your pitch function you would just use this as follows:

```
void Camera::pitch( float angleInRadians ) {
    clamp( -85.0f, 85.0f, angleInRadians );

    mRotation *= Quaternionf(AngleAxisf(-angleInRadians, Vector3f::UnitX()));
    mRotation.normalize();
}
```

Or

```
void Camera::pitch( float angleInRadians, float min, float max ) {
    clamp( min, max, angleInRadians );

    mRotation *= Quaternionf(AngleAxisf(-angleInRadians, Vector3f::UnitX()));
    mRotation.normalize();
}
```

I think this should solve your problem and also it removes the if statement checking for validity. I omitted you last statement within your function for I wasn't sure if it is needed for your class or not, but I believe that it wasn't important enough to write it out in this answer in the answering of your question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer the question. I should make it clearer that the angle in radians is being accumulated into mRotation... You have me thinking though... I could store "pitch" as a member variable and use that as a way to do book keeping on the pitch of the orientation. The problem with this approach though is that the `pitch()` func isn't the only API that I support which would affect the pitch value. I also want to support a lookAt(vec3 target, vec3 camPos) function. I suppose I could calculate the pitch in that function explicitly though to maintain the pitch value.

Comment: You could make the camera have these members and always use shared_ptr for your resources to make sure that all areas have the data in synchronization.

Comment: Also; even if you took a different approach that works for your needs; the provided template clamp function is always useful in many other areas, for reusable generic code. I use this quite often in my 3D Graphics Engine; however when I switched from OpenGL v1.0 to 3.5-4.5 I started to use GLM which has its own clamp function.